# which database is suitable for heavy load- viz thousands of users simultaneously using my app- Dynamo DB/MongoDB/SQL Azure/other?

Tags: database

I am designing a web app which may have heavy loads, and I am considering which database should I use for it?

Should I go in for a no-sql database like Amazon Dynamo DB or Mongo DB, or should I stick to RDBMS like MySQL or SQL Azure? Which of these options will be suitable for use under heavy loads, eg thousands of updates/inserts per second, and which db will scale up well to increasing loads?

UPDATE-  The application will require lots of simultaneous inserts, less of updates... It involves facebook users sending wall posts to their chosen friends as part of a game...Also a user can see all posts sent to him/sent by him through the application. It is planned to be a java web app but database is not yet finalised.